# What are the true meaning of Hold sway , Jest and Jabbed?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Ok , So After reading This sentence :

As Russia has changed rapidly in the past six years , so has its sense of humor, The political Joke **held sway** , the secret **jest** that **jabbed** at 70 years of repressive regimes.

I've find difficulties understanding the meaning of the paragraph due to my poor vocabulary , so i looked at The oxford dictionary and google translator and i came up with following ;

**Hold sway** : Dominate , have a controlling influence over

**a Jest** : a Joke

**Jab** : Poke

After I Re-read again the text i still have difficulties understanding it ,  are the synonyms wrong ?? If so , What are the correct ones ?, 
Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting article on the difference between "joke" and "jest": http://the-difference-between.com/jest/joke - jest is an action, and may also have connotations of a "jester", which was a role in some medieval courts which was like an in-house comedian/entertainer who was often given more license to mock the establishment than the average person - which may have some relevance in this context of mocking the Communist party.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much correct, with an additional comment: "jab" in boxing terms is a short, straight punch designed to knock your opponent back and open him up for the knockout punch and I suspect that is at least partially relevant, given the context. It is also a colloquial term for a medical injection but that's not the meaning here.

Comment: In the sense of poking fun, a "jab" is a minor "poke", but likely one that hits a sore spot.  Eg, your drinking buddy brings up how well your ex is doing after she divorced you and married that other guy.